# Wordpress website is redirecting on some different shopping page

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, hacked

we are facing below issues
1 - Our wordpress admin panel is not opening. when tried to open admin panel it redirects to our site homepage
2 - Our site Navigation panel button are also redirecting to homepage only 3 - If you search "Twopir" on google and try to open the link then it redirects to online shopping site

-I tried to check the file information from the cpanel but that page also showing the error while fetching the information. because of that we are unable to do the manually plugin.

Comment: If you are unable to access your site files via cpanel you should contact your hosting provider for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your site has been hacked. You will need to do thorough checking of all files and plugins to fix it. Lots of info on the googles/bings/ducks to help clean up your site. Will take some time and effort.

Basics would be

- manually update everything (download files, unzip locally, upload). Do this for WP core, themes, plugins.
- check all files for hacked content. Look at hidden files, ICO files, etc, for obfusticated code.
- check htaccess files for bad stuff. Do that in all folders on the site.
- repeat the above process to ensure clean.
- you may need to look at the posts database.
- it will take some days for search results to show a clean site. You can resubmit your sitemap to the search engines to help speed that up.

Some people will say 'nuke from orbit', but you can (I have done this) clean up a site manually. Will take hours, though. Good luck.